# Magento : Catalog Price Index showing processing due to catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx table doesnot exist

Tags: database, magento

When i reindex catalog Price from shell it gives error 
"Product Prices index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_name.catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx' doesn't exist' in /home/site_directory/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228".

The table "catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx"  actually shows in left column in phpmyadmin
as you can see in screenshot. But when you try to click on that it says "The table doesnot exist"  .

Also when we try to create the table by executing sql query it says  "the table already exist"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for a complete day i manage to figured out the solution with the help of my hosting solution. Here is the complete solution [Click Here](http://developerafroz.blogspot.in/2014/05/magento-1146-table-doesnt-exist.html)